# CLISP FFI Foreign Value Issues

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, clisp

I'm trying to use the CLISP FFI to call some Win32 functions.

I was able to make a call out and have *that* call a callback in Lisp, but now I can't figure out how to access the values passed to the callback.

One of the values is a pointer to a `struct`. I have the structure defined ok, I can print it and get a `#<FOREIGN-VARIABLE #x00000000>` or wrap it in `foreign-address` and get `#<FOREIGN-ADDRESS #x00000000>` (not the real value or addr in either), but when I try to `deref` it I get the following:

```
*** - FFI:DEREF is only allowed after FFI:FOREIGN-VALUE:
  (FFI:DEREF (FFI:FOREIGN-ADDRESS PRECT*))
```

I've tried to wrap the `foreign-address` call in `foreign-value`, tried to use `with-c-place`, and other things, but nothing works. I either get nothing printed (in which case I assume there was an error during the call and it borked), or I get that error.

The only documentation I've been able to find is [this dffi reference](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html) but it has scant examples and the documentation for those functions isn't clear.

Anyone have any pointers? (Pun!) Should I switch to CFFI/UFFI or SBCL even?

**Update**

I got it to print the struct out *once* after wrapping the pointer in `foreign-value` re`load`ing it in the REPL (without exiting), then it seemed to error in the callback for subsequent re`load`s.

**Edit**

Still can't get it working; here's the code:

```
(defpackage "WIN32")
(in-package "WIN32")
(use-package "FFI")

; Listen for a WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message to get notifications of when
; a monitor (setting) is added/removed/changed



(def-c-type BOOL     boolean)
(def-c-type CHAR     char)
(def-c-type DWORD    uint)
(def-c-type HANDLE   c-pointer)
(def-c-type HDC      HANDLE)
(def-c-type HMONITOR HANDLE)
(def-c-type HWND     HANDLE)
(def-c-type LONG     long)
(def-c-type LPARAM   c-pointer)
(def-c-type LPCSTR   c-string)
(def-c-type LPCTSTR  LPCSTR) ; LPCWSTR
;(def-c-type LPCWSTR  )
(def-c-type TCHAR    CHAR) ; WCHAR
;(def-c-type WCHAR    )


(defun symbol-to-keyword (sym)
  (intern (symbol-name sym) :keyword))


(defun affix-to-symbol (prefix sym suffix)
  (intern (concatenate 'string prefix (symbol-name sym) suffix)))


(defun car-symbol-to-keyword (pair)
  (cons
    (symbol-to-keyword (car pair))
    (cdr pair)))



(defmacro def-struct-type (name &rest fields)
  `(progn
    (def-c-struct ,name ,@fields)
    (def-c-type
      ,(affix-to-symbol "P" name "")
      (c-pointer ,name))
    (defconstant
      ,(affix-to-symbol "" name "-INSTANCE")
      '(c-struct ,name ,@(mapcar #'car-symbol-to-keyword fields)))
    ))


;typedef struct _RECT {
;  LONG left;
;  LONG top;
;  LONG right;
;  LONG bottom;
;} RECT, *PRECT;

(def-struct-type RECT
  (left   LONG)
  (top    LONG)
  (right  LONG)
  (bottom LONG))


;BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(
;  _In_  HMONITOR hMonitor,
;  _In_  HDC hdcMonitor,
;  _In_  LPRECT lprcMonitor,
;  _In_  LPARAM dwData
;);

;BOOL EnumDisplayMonitors(
;  _In_  HDC hdc,
;  _In_  LPCRECT lprcClip,
;  _In_  MONITORENUMPROC lpfnEnum,
;  _In_  LPARAM dwData
;);


(def-call-out EnumDisplayMonitors
  (:name "EnumDisplayMonitors")
  (:library "User32.dll")
  (:arguments
    (hdc      HDC)
    (lprcClip PRECT)
    (lpfnEnum 
      (c-function
        (:arguments
          (hMonitor    HMONITOR)
          (hdcMonitor  HDC)
          (lprcMonitor PRECT)
          (dwData      LPARAM))
        (:return-type BOOL)
        (:language :stdc-stdcall)))
    (dwData   LPARAM))
  (:return-type BOOL)
  (:language :stdc-stdcall))
(export 'EnumDisplayMonitors)


(defun callback (hmon hdc* prect* data)
  (progn
    (format t "~A ~A ~A ~A~%" hmon hdc* (foreign-address prect*) data)
    t))

(EnumDisplayMonitors nil nil #'callback nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use `slot` and `c-var-object`

See [`slot`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html#slot) and [`c-var-object`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html#c-var-object).

### More examples

You can find more examples in

- [tests/ffi.tst](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/tests/ffi.tst)
- [modules/bindings/glibc/tests.tst](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/bindings/glibc/tests.tst) and [modules/bindings/glibc/linux.lisp](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/bindings/glibc/linux.lisp)
- [modules/bindings/win32/tests.tst](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/bindings/win32/tests.tst) and [modules/bindings/win32/win32.lisp](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/bindings/win32/win32.lisp)
- [modules/dbus/tests.tst](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/dbus/tests.tst) and [modules/dbus/dbus.lisp](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/dbus/dbus.lisp)
- more ffi modules

### Future

Indeed, these days sbcl is better maintained than clisp, so you might want to consider switching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried messing with those, but still can't get things working. I've updated my question to include the code. Btw, I'm working on a 64-bit OS, I wonder if that's screwing things up?